# Find out internals of a system-defined style in Windows Phone

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, styling, blend

Whenever I set a style to a `TextBlock`, I am defining a certain FontFamily and FontSize, that are defined within the style.

I am to style the `TextBox`, so that it looks exactly the same, as `TextBlock`, but with the border around it.

I am applying `Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"` to my TextBox. In SilverlightSpy I see that it sets the FontSize to 32 pt. But in reallity it is most likely uses something like `<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>` within the `PhoneTextLargeStyle`.

How can I find the breakdown of the setters in a predefined Windows Phone style?

Is there perhaps an easier way to tune `TextBox` to look exactly the same as `TextBlock`, without defining a custom style for the former one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All default styles you can find in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Design\System.Windows.xaml`

The system-wide text styles are in Design\ThemeResources.xaml

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find the breakdown of the setters in a predefined Windows Phone style?

You can extract the template using Expression Blend. It's automatically done when you choose to define a custom style.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to get to the contents of a style like PhoneTextLargeStyle, not a style of a control.

Comment: You can find the "contents" of that on MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552(v=vs.92).aspx , anyway, I thought you meant the style of the TextBlock control, not the Text styles.